# How to solve this error: "Creating default object from empty value"

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following code in one of my controllers:

```
public function branch(Request $request){
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $code = $request->input('code');

    $branch->name = $name;
    $branch->code = $code;

    $branch->save();
}
```

And when I run the code, I have this error:

> Creating default object from empty value

Please help! Am a beginner. Laravel 5.

---

EDIT

Here's my whole code:

```
use App\branch;
class AddController extends Controller {

public function branch(Request $request){

    $branch->name = $request->input('name');
    $branch->code = $request->input('code');

    $branch->save();
}
```

Comment: What is `$branch` supposed to be, do you mean to create a specific kind of object there?

Comment: It's an Eloquent modal...

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel but that sounds extremely unlikely. Do you perhaps mean something like `$this->branch`?

Comment: No... branch is an eloquent model... It's included like this
`use App\branch`

Comment: If it were, you wouldn't be receiving that error message...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not sure I got you...

Comment: in which line is the error?

Comment: `$branch` is an undefined variable. Note that namespaces don't affect variables.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer in the line `$name = $request->input('name');`

Comment: `$branch` isn't in scope for the method, simple as that.... where is your and how is your `$branch` instance defined

Comment: @jeroen Would you suggest I add this line to the code:

`$branch = new branch;`

Comment: If you don't already have an instance of your branch model, then yes.... you need to do `$branch = new branch;` to instantiate it

Comment: @jeroen Yeah.. that solved it!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this:

```
$branch = new branch();
```

if you wish to add a new record.

And if you want to update rows you need to find the data first.

```
$branch = Branch::find(primaryId);
```

or if you have no primary key us this

```
$branch = Branch::where(['columnName' => value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to add

```
$branch = new branch;
```